# WSO2 Identity / PAP rejects Condition Logic with Multiple Statements (XML Editor & Upload)

Tags: wso2, identity, xacml

When using XACML V.3 "Condition" logic that contains multiple statements I receive an error at saving a new policy. The WSO2 XML editor, as well as the policy "Upload" function, reject the source code attached below, throwing the following error message:

**Error**

```
Policy uploading failed. Unsupported Entitlement Policy. Policy can not be parsed
```

or

```
Entitlement policy is not updated. Error is :Unsupported Entitlement Policy. Policy can not be parsed
```

Below you find a sample code of a policy that makes use of a "Condition" logic. The source code was previously validated with the XACML version 3 schema and was found as valid.

**Source Code Sample:**

```
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"  PolicyId="cfatest4" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:deny-overrides" Version="1.0">
   <Target></Target>
   <Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="Deny-Rule1">
    <Target></Target>
    <Condition>
           <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:not">
           <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:any-of">
                <Function FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal"/>
                <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">myGroup</AttributeValue>
        <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-one-and-only">
        <AttributeDesignator
                        AttributeId="http://w3.RED.com/subject/groupsUserBelong"
                        DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
            Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject"
                MustBePresent="false"/>
                </Apply>
               </Apply>
            </Apply>
     </Condition>
      <ObligationExpressions>
         <ObligationExpression FulfillOn="Deny" ObligationId="groupscheck">
            <AttributeAssignmentExpression AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:example:attribute:text">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Rule 1 - The groups validation error</AttributeValue>
            </AttributeAssignmentExpression>
         </ObligationExpression>
         <ObligationExpression ObligationId="debug1" FulfillOn="Deny">
            <AttributeAssignmentExpression AttributeId="debug1">
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://w3.RED.com/subject/groupsUserBelong" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="false"></AttributeDesignator>
            </AttributeAssignmentExpression>
         </ObligationExpression>
      </ObligationExpressions>
   </Rule>
   <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Permit-Rule1">
      <Target>
         <AnyOf>
            <AllOf>
               <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">ldap</AttributeValue>
                  <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
               </Match>
            </AllOf>
         </AnyOf>
         <AnyOf>
            <AllOf>
               <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
                  <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
               </Match>
            </AllOf>
         </AnyOf>
      </Target>
      <ObligationExpressions>
         <ObligationExpression FulfillOn="Permit" ObligationId="countrycheck">
            <AttributeAssignmentExpression AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:example:attribute:text">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Rule 1: The Bluegroups validation passed successfully</AttributeValue>
            </AttributeAssignmentExpression>
         </ObligationExpression>
      </ObligationExpressions>
   </Rule>
   <ObligationExpressions>
      <ObligationExpression FulfillOn="Permit" ObligationId="allchecks">
         <AttributeAssignmentExpression AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:example:attribute:text">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">The overall validation passed successfully</AttributeValue>
         </AttributeAssignmentExpression>
      </ObligationExpression>
   </ObligationExpressions>
</Policy>
```

The error started after adding additional parser logic into the "Condition" block.